# What does the phrase "in all of its moods" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> I said that when I grew up I would own a house right here in Sea Bright. I would be able to look at the ocean every day, **in all of its moods**, even when the wind howled in winter and smashed the sea into boiling white.

Source: *[Dreams Do Come True](http://houyhnhnm96.blogspot.it/2013/06/dreams-do-come-true.html)*

What does the phrase "in all of its moods" mean?

Comment: What do you think the "mood" of the ocean would mean?

Comment: To help us help you, Yethu, it's best if you share some info about where your attempt to understand it on your own broke down.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"In all of its moods"

^ It would mean the ocean is either calm, turbulent . . . etc.

Comment: Yes, it's a personification of the ocean, comparing its state to the emotional state of human beings.  If you don't think the ocean can be angry, then you haven't live through a gale.

Comment: ... There's an article at [LiteraryDevices.net](http://literarydevices.net/pathetic-fallacy/) saying that pathetic fallacy is intermediate between literal usage and personification proper. This becomes a philosophical debate: can one really speak meaningfully about the _moods_ of the ocean when you've not 'lived through a gale' etc? (Though even considering such scenarios, perhaps on newly-discovered planets, demands intelligent involvement.)